# INDEX returns wrong value and no value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find matching values and sort them in a column. 
Column A contains Names and Column B Training Done by person in Column A.

An example of my data can be seen here:

[image: Data]

Having that data, I want to get a separate table with two Columns(Name and training). In Column C, I want the names and in Column D I want the training done by who is in Column C.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,SMALL(IF($C2=$A$2:$A$7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)-1,""),ROWS($D$1:D1))),"No training done")
```

I've tried using the above formula, but it seems to only work for the first entry in the table. I can't figure out what i should change.

This is what I get

[image: Formula result]

It shows "No training done" to people who have had training and there's a "0" where it should be "No training done".

This is my expected result:

[image: Result]

**L.E** : Anna did Excel. A mistake on my part in the above picture.
 Also, I'm only interested in the Training Column, as I already got the hang of the formula to order the names.

Thank you.

Comment: When you are using Small, it is expected one matrix and one position, and you are returning back a number ROW($A$2:$A$7)-1, that is why it is working just on the first row. When you go for the second element with just one number on the matrix, there is no value to return.

Comment: I suggest you to use a helper column to replace blank entry with 'No training done', then create a pivot table including the helper column, and show the training per person in the pivot table. If you want to keep the names in the original order, you can add another helper column to give an index number to each entry and when you create the pivot table you can sort the data in the same order as in the original data set. `#powerquery` can do the job using the same logic if you are dealing with a much larger data set and you do not want to use helper columns.

Comment: Why doesn't Anna had any training done? Is that a mistake on your side in the expected output?

Comment: @JvdV Yea, It's a mistake by my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula in `D2:D7`:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( $A$2:$A$7,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
MATCH( $A$2:$A$7, $A$2:$A$7, 0 ),
ROWS( B2:B$2 ) ) ), "" )
```

[image]

Then enter this formula in `E2:E7`

```
= IFERROR( TRIM( SUBSTITUTE( REPT( " ", 3 ) & INDEX( $B$2:$B$7,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW(E:E) / ( ( $A$2:$A$7 = D2 ) * 1 ),
COUNTIF( D$2:D2, D2) ) ) & REPT( " ", 3 ), REPT( " ", 6 ), "No Training done" ) ), "" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(Training,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(C2=Names)*ROW(Names),COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,$C2))-1)
```

[image]

In this instance, I used a custom format for the result of: `;;"No Training Done";@`

but, if you don't mind a longer formula, you can use an `IF` function to return the `No Training Done` statement in the event the formula returns nothing.

```
=IF(INDEX(Training,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(C2=Names)*ROW(Names),COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,$C2))-1)=0,"No Training Done",INDEX(Training,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(C2=Names)*ROW(Names),COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,$C2))-1))
```

Also, you can use whole-column references if you want.  If you do that, remove the `-1` as you won't have to adjust for the header row.

If you wanted to use `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`, it would just be a matter of replacing the *null* with `No Training Done` and then sorting the result per your desired order.  That can all be done from the PQ Editor GUI, and below is the M-code

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Names", type text}, {"Training", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,"No Training Done",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Training"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Replaced Value",{{"Names", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way will be:

1) Copy and paste your information to columns C:D

2) On cell A:2 place `=COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)` and drag it to your row range.

3) On cell B:2 place `=C2&A2` and drag it to your row range.

4) On cell E:2 place `=B2` and drag it to your row range.

5) On cell F:2 place `=IF(VLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$D$7,3,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$D$7,3,FALSE))`

6) Hide columns A:B

Hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't really help, it doesn't sort the names ( which I already did) and if I want to sort out more entries and for example look for  only 3 people it won;t work.